# Fill the empty values with lastknown value in kusto kql

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Let example i have one master table

The ID 1, 2 having empty values for X column

| ID | DateTime | IngestionTime | X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2012-12-28T12:04:00 | 2012-12-28T12:04:00 | 12 | 11 | 10 |
| 2 | 2012-12-28T12:06:00 | 2012-12-28T12:06:00 | 2 | 9 | 7 |
| 3 | 2012-12-29T12:11:00 | 2012-12-29T12:11:00 | 2 | 9 | 7 |
| 1 | 2012-12-29T12:15:00 | 2012-12-29T12:15:00 |  | 33 | 7 |
| 2 | 2012-12-29T12:24:00 | 2012-12-29T12:24:00 |  | 9 | 7 |

I'm having in function demo(datetime:fromTime, datetime:toTime)
from this I'm querying for fromTime 2012-12-29T12:11:00 to toTime: same 29thdecmber)
so if  any empty values there i need   to fill
those empty values  from previous date with respective column

Need a filled x value for the same ID from the master table

| ID | DateTime | IngestionTime | X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2012-12-28T12:04:00 | 2012-12-28T12:04:00 | 12 | 11 | 10 |
| 2 | 2012-12-28T12:06:00 | 2012-12-28T12:06:00 | 2 | 9 | 7 |
| 3 | 2012-12-29T12:11:00 | 2012-12-29T12:11:00 | 2 | 9 | 7 |
| 1 | 2012-12-29T12:15:00 | 2012-12-29T12:15:00 | lastknownvalueforthisID? | 33 | 7 |
| 2 | 2012-12-29T12:24:00 | 2012-12-29T12:24:00 | lastknownvalueforthisID? | 9 | 7 |

Comment: Please fixed the required results (replace filledX  with real values)

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz can you please help on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
datatable(ID:int, DateTime:datetime, IngestionTime:datetime, X:int, Y:int, Z:int)
[
    1 ,datetime(2012-12-28T12:04:00) ,datetime(2012-12-28T12:04:00) ,12        ,11 ,10
   ,2 ,datetime(2012-12-28T12:06:00) ,datetime(2012-12-28T12:06:00) ,2         ,9  ,7
   ,3 ,datetime(2012-12-29T12:11:00) ,datetime(2012-12-29T12:11:00) ,2         ,9  ,7
   ,1 ,datetime(2012-12-29T12:15:00) ,datetime(2012-12-29T12:15:00) ,int(null) ,33 ,7
   ,2 ,datetime(2012-12-29T12:24:00) ,datetime(2012-12-29T12:24:00) ,int(null) ,9  ,7
]
| partition hint.strategy=native by ID
  (
    order by DateTime asc 
    | scan with (step s: true => X = coalesce(X, s.X);)
  )
```

| ID | DateTime | IngestionTime | X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2012-12-28T12:04:00Z | 2012-12-28T12:04:00Z | 12 | 11 | 10 |
| 1 | 2012-12-29T12:15:00Z | 2012-12-29T12:15:00Z | 12 | 33 | 7 |
| 3 | 2012-12-29T12:11:00Z | 2012-12-29T12:11:00Z | 2 | 9 | 7 |
| 2 | 2012-12-28T12:06:00Z | 2012-12-28T12:06:00Z | 2 | 9 | 7 |
| 2 | 2012-12-29T12:24:00Z | 2012-12-29T12:24:00Z | 2 | 9 | 7 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA4WSy2rDMBBF9wb/wyxlUIMl9xUXd%20VN9lm4LV0otkgErhysSUsgH99R5ISm2IkeaNDVPQwzahTSXLWaLcrcWORQKtRL86XzhgKkgMPCrrVD09l/91VwvIXj3R9JHH3EEdAQwE8vmUyFvKMln5dC5ul9nqbJTVlIGAYXBBPpkcvltPHxOneQz1jgc9pPAZuN%20ebeJ8QU9kIex45WIfgermMHmWrK7K5tKcyyM3a0CEefnCzuhfwHO2T7GUcH2Koeje80bOjFzGFPmPW%20sArNt4bVHhalz4CFHnd9o3t/e/o0oFwNQTuAq5WFH4MbYA71FlwO2O80FK9QQQF1p1rtas0qDm5WJS%20JNya/%202nBMJICAAA=)

Comment: Thanks David, had tried this above answer but can't process for larger data two days of telemetry data it's failing with can't partition query runway

Comment: Replace the hint.strategy from native to shuffle

Comment: Query Limits Exceeded 




Tried with Shuffle still same error
 Query execution has exceeded the allowed limits (80DA0001): 'partition' operator has exceeded the memory budget (5368709120) during evaluation. Results may be incorrect or incomplete (E_RUNAWAY_QUERY; see https://aka.ms/kustoquerylimits)..

Comment: [Limit on memory per iterator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/concepts/querylimits#limit-on-memory-per-iterator)

Comment: This actually answers your real scenario and if you'll follow the link in the comment above, you'll see how to tweak the memory limitation.

Comment: Im dealing with millionstelemetry data, above not effective if u have large sample u can also try , tried everything  mentioned in the link , can anyother possible approach like materialized view etc

Answer (score 0):

If the gaps are always at the end, you can use the following query.

```
let t = datatable(ID:int, DateTime:datetime, IngestionTime:datetime, X:int, Y:int, Z:int)
[
    1 ,datetime(2012-12-28T12:04:00) ,datetime(2012-12-28T12:04:00) ,12        ,11 ,10
   ,2 ,datetime(2012-12-28T12:06:00) ,datetime(2012-12-28T12:06:00) ,2         ,9  ,7
   ,3 ,datetime(2012-12-29T12:11:00) ,datetime(2012-12-29T12:11:00) ,2         ,9  ,7
   ,1 ,datetime(2012-12-29T12:15:00) ,datetime(2012-12-29T12:15:00) ,int(null) ,33 ,7
   ,2 ,datetime(2012-12-29T12:24:00) ,datetime(2012-12-29T12:24:00) ,int(null) ,9  ,7
];
let last_notnull_X_values = 
t
| where isnotnull(X)
| summarize arg_max(DateTime, X) by ID
| project ID, new_X = X;
t
| lookup last_notnull_X_values on ID
| extend X = coalesce(X, new_X)
| project-away n`ew_X
```

| ID | DateTime | IngestionTime | X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2012-12-28T12:04:00Z | 2012-12-28T12:04:00Z | 12 | 11 | 10 |
| 2 | 2012-12-28T12:06:00Z | 2012-12-28T12:06:00Z | 2 | 9 | 7 |
| 3 | 2012-12-29T12:11:00Z | 2012-12-29T12:11:00Z | 2 | 9 | 7 |
| 1 | 2012-12-29T12:15:00Z | 2012-12-29T12:15:00Z | 12 | 33 | 7 |
| 2 | 2012-12-29T12:24:00Z | 2012-12-29T12:24:00Z | 2 | 9 | 7 |

[Fidlde](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA4WSTW%20DMAyG70j8Bx9BSiWS7qtUu3HpvQe2aUIptTq2kFQQRjvtx8%20UtGor6BKiBL9%20n0SWFVqw8AxraWmuFAaLJC60ZZBIi8uixJgktHRgsNAbrG1h9FU87R0v/fbabaHvvfke0ODAjpmBiLiY0CeellzE0V0cReG/MhfgBuME49GBy8S48eE218knLLAZrcceOx3yzTof52PYC3kYO1iF3nd/G%20tkqmmgG6XoOJ2esINFOPjEaHEv5DOse%20373PcUdYWStc20sZ2apdm3VA3W1Cm%20Z33vF9oPrBCK2mUEadhF66YsZVX8IMhqk5VyFxzbiLokhNUeFkmXt63MJ%20aW/hhobLOUwOncoZUxX8125AFGOwTuLOo1dM7cSIV1jkHqaOHZHRPZyn0f/gPtobWn7QIAAA==)

Comment: In my case having empty values at middle only not at end

Comment: In that case, the data sample you have provided does not reflect the actual scenario. Accept one of the answers and post a new question.

Comment: Accepted the above one , Please look on this ,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74961725/fill-empty-values-with-their-respective-respective-key