# Fill Empty values with their respective respective KEY

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Lets example ,Have one master Table contains the telemetry data for every 5 seconds one record
having millions of data in this table

| ID | DateTime | IngestionTime | X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2012-12-28T12:04:00 | 2012-12-28T12:04:00 | 12 | 11 | 10 |
| 2 | 2012-12-28T12:06:00 | 2012-12-28T12:06:00 | 2 | 9 | 7 |
| 3 | 2012-12-29T12:11:00 | 2012-12-29T12:11:00 | 2 | 9 | 7 |
| 1 | 2012-12-29T12:15:00 | 2012-12-29T12:15:00 |  | 33 | 7 |
| 2 | 2012-12-29T12:24:00 | 2012-12-29T12:24:00 |  | 9 | 72 |
| 3 | 2012-12-29T12:30:00 | 2012-12-29T12:30:00 | 44 | 40 | 54 |
| 4 | 2012-12-29T12:35:00 | 2012-12-29T12:35:00 | 11 | 9 | 92 |

I'm having in function demo(datetime:fromTime, datetime:toTime)
from this I'm querying for fromTime 2012-12-29T12:11:00 to toTime: same 29thdecmber)
so if  any empty values there i need   to fill
those empty values  from previous date with respective column

Requirement to fill this lastknownvalue in very optimized way since we are delaing with millions of data

| ID | DateTime | IngestionTime | X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2012-12-28T12:04:00 | 2012-12-28T12:04:00 | 12 | 11 | 10 |
| 2 | 2012-12-28T12:06:00 | 2012-12-28T12:06:00 | 8 | 9 | 7 |
| 3 | 2012-12-29T12:11:00 | 2012-12-29T12:11:00 | 2 | 9 | 7 |
| 1 | 2012-12-29T12:15:00 | 2012-12-29T12:15:00 | lastKnownValueForThisID? | 33 | 7 |
| 2 | 2012-12-29T12:24:00 | 2012-12-29T12:24:00 | lastKnownValueForThisID | 9 | 72 |
| 3 | 2012-12-29T12:30:00 | 2012-12-29T12:30:00 | 44 | 40 | 54 |
| 4 | 2012-12-29T12:35:00 | 2012-12-29T12:35:00 | 11 | 9 | 92 |

Comment: Can you provide an example using the "datatable()" construct? Would be good to have a full example dataset and the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I fully understand the question, however for filling missing values in a time series, there are a few useful builtin functions, for example [series_fill_backward()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/series-fill-backwardfunction), [series_fill_const()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/series-fill-backwardfunction) and more.